# How to update password in laravel project?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

The problem is that I should update password by submitResetPasswordForm only by password, not showing email and having in user table the forgot_password_token, not having password_resets table. Can somebody help me?
Somthing like this but with condition: not have a separate table for resset password, adding only a forgot_password_token, and update password without having in a submiting form email.
https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-custom-forgot-reset-password-exampleexample.html

in my controller:

```
class ForgetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    public function showForgetPasswordForm()
    {
        return view('auth.forgetPassword');
    }

   
    public function submitForgetPasswordForm(ForgetPasswordRequest $request)
    {
        $request->validated();

        $forgot_password_token = Str::random(64);

        if (DB::table('poll_users')->where('name','email', \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::get('email'))->exists()) {
            DB::table('poll_users')->insert([
                'forgot_password_token' => $forgot_password_token,
        ]);
        }

        Mail::send('email.forgetPassword', ['forgot_password_token' => $forgot_password_token], function ($message) use ($request) {
            $message->to($request->email);
            $message->subject('Reset Password');
        });

        return back()->with('message', 'We have e-mailed your password reset link!');
    }

   
    public function showResetPasswordForm($forgot_password_token)
    {
        return view('auth.forgetPasswordLink', ['forgot_password_token' => $forgot_password_token]);
    }

   
    public function submitResetPasswordForm(SubmitResetPasswordRequest $request)
    {
      $request->validated();

      $updatePassword = DB::table('poll_users')
            ->where([
                'forgot_password_token' => $request->forgot_password_token
            ])
            ->first();

        if(!$updatePassword){
            return back()->withInput()->with('error', 'Invalid token!');
        }

        $user = DB::table('poll_users')->where(['email'=> $email])->update(['password' => Hash::make($request->password)]);


//            if (DB::table('poll_users')->where('name','email')->exists()){
//                $updatePassword = DB::table('poll_users')->update(['password' => Hash::make($request->password)]);
//            }

        return redirect('/login')->with('message', 'Your password has been changed!');
    }
}
```

in the form:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Reset Password</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST"
                              action="{{ route('reset.password.post') }}">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            @if(session()->has('message'))
                                <div class="alert alert-success">
                                    {{ session()->get('message') }}
                                </div>
                            @endif
                            <input type="hidden" name="forgot_password_token" value="{{ $forgot_password_token}}">
                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" name="password"
                                           value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>
                                    @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                        <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('password') }}</span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="password" id="password_confirmation" class="form-control"
                                           name="password_confirmation" required autofocus>
                                    @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                        <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Reset Password
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


@endsection
```

in the ForgetPasswordRequest

```
 class ForgetPasswordRequest extends FormRequest
    {
        /**
         * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
         *
         * @return bool
         */
        public function authorize()
        {
            return true;
        }
    
        /**
         * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
         *
         * @return array
         */
        public function rules()
        {
            return [
                'email' => 'required|email|exists:poll_users',
            ];
        }
    
        public function withValidator($validator)
        {
            return $validator->errors()->all();
        }
in the SubmitResetPasswordRequest

SubmitResetPasswordRequest extends FormRequest
    {
        /**
         * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
         *
         * @return bool
         */
        public function authorize()
        {
            return true;
        }
    
        /**
         * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
         *
         * @return array
         */
        public function rules()
        {
            return [
    
                'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
                'forgot_password_token' => 'string'
            ];
        }
    
        public function withValidator($validator)
        {
            return $validator->errors()->all();
        }
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'password'], function () {
Route::get('forget', 'Auth\ForgetPasswordController@showForgetPasswordForm')->name('forget.password.get');
Route::post('forget', 'Auth\ForgetPasswordController@submitForgetPasswordForm')->name('forget.password.post');
Route::get('reset/{token}', 'Auth\ForgetPasswordController@showResetPasswordForm')->name('reset.password.get');
Route::post('reset', 'Auth\ForgetPasswordController@submitResetPasswordForm')->name('reset.password.post');
});
```

in the poll_users
id,name, email, password,active,role,remember_token, forgot_password_token, department_id

Comment: simply make a controller function and call that function. Write your update password code in that function.

Comment: could you please share what you have done

Comment: I don t know how to update password in the db

Comment: This depends on the authentication middleware, but two examples are 1. [Resetting Passwords Tutorial by Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passwords) or simply 2. `$user->password = $request->get('new_password');` or whatever your request and new password form parameter are. Then `$user->save()` our middleware does the password hashing for us.